# React folder structure suggestions with Java as backend

Tags: java, reactjs, redux, structure, directory

I am building a React Redux folder structure with Java as backend language. I am using facebook/create-react-app as a boilerplate. I wanted to do more customizations, so I `eject`ed it. There is a `paths.js`. How can I modify this file to do what I want? I'd love to get some suggestions if possible.

Below is the current folder structure:

```
project/
  admin/
    src/
     webapp/
       config/
       node_modules/
       public/
       scripts/
       src/
         components/
           App.js
         index.js
         index.html
       package.json
       yarn.lock
```

Below is the folder structure I want to have. The reason I want to do it is because I want to simply run `yarn build` in root directory without having to `cd` all the way down to `webapp`.

```
project/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  yarn.lock
  admin/
    src/
     webapp/
       config/
       public/
       scripts/
       src/
         components/
           App.js
         index.js
         index.html
```

But the problems are:

1. Now when I am in `webapp/`, I don't have `npm commands` anymore since `package.json' is in root.
2. Now that `package.json` is in root, does that mean I have to change all the paths of `node_modules/` when using `import .. from ../`?
3. Are there any best practices on folder structure with Java as backend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't move your package.json, just create a new one in project/ like this :

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd admin/src/webapp && yarn build"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it good tho? Have two `package.json` file in two different `directories`?

Comment: I don't know if it's "good" or not but it's better than doing a mess with your folder structure, especially if you have multiple subprojects. You can also create an executable file to run scripts.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a project with 2 `package.json`s in different `directory` maybe find a way to make them `symlinks` or `absolute path` is a better solution.